# PHPExcel import more than 500 rows

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have the code that can save the uploaded csv file in the database. But the problem is that it can only save 100-200 rows out of more than 1000 rows. I have an idea to save rows batch by batch instead of a whole but i don't know how to code it.

```
require_once 'PHPexcel/PHPExcel.php';
    $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($file);

    foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {
        $worksheetTitle     = $worksheet->getTitle();
        $highestRow         = $worksheet->getHighestRow();
        $highestColumn      = $worksheet->getHighestColumn();
        $highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn);

        for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; ++ $row) {
            $val=array();
            for ($col = 0; $col < $highestColumnIndex; ++ $col) {
                $cell = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row);
                $val[] = $cell->getValue();
            }

        }
}
```

Comment: what stops it going above 100-200 rows?

Comment: @nogad i get internal server error 500 after saving the records. But not all rows are saved.

Comment: Are you doing this through the browser, for example not on the command line?  Your script is probably exceeding the max execution time.  `set_time_limit(-1);`  http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php  I should mention there will probably be apache time limits too that this wont get around, but they are likely higher.  PHP's default is like 30 seconds or such.

Comment: cure the disease not the symptom, make sure your error logging, and check